# "Static" class member 

Tags: c++

For example, `x` is `static` in class's definition. 
I should use `x` in this way:

`class_name::x`; rather than `instance_of_class.x;`

My question is, is the latter one also legal? Or just not correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is legal and correct, but the general consensus is to use the **scope resolution operator**.

```
class_name::x
```

rather than

```
instance.x
```

Comment: The only time I've used `.` was in a template function where it was only sometimes a static member.

Answer (score 4):

Both are valid. The reason to prefer use the first one is to make a reader of your code to understand that the member is static and belongs to the whole class of objects rather than each particular instance.